# Why is it not recommended to deploy multiple microservices on a single virtual machine?

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, microservices

Why is it always suggested to deploy one micro-service per a Virtual Machine/Container?

Why can't we deploy all micro-services on a single virtual machine?

**Example :**  We can easily host multiple applications on Apache tomcat which will be on one machine

Comment: Where is it 'always suggested to deploy one micro-service per a Virtual Machine'? I don't accept the premise of the question.

Comment: @TomW It is typically one micro service per a container. I just added Virtual Machine there for better clarity. The main motive is to know why it is not recommended to deploy multiple micro-services on a VM or on a single operating system instance?

Comment: c.f. [this article](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/3-reasons-why-you-should-always-run-microservices-apps-containers) and others - but I'd like to understand why a little better myself. So far all I hear is "then people might actually have to keep track of stuff".

Comment: Ok, yea to @TomW , I would agree with him even though I posted my answer below. When this question is made available, container orchestration was still relatively in its early days but today, we can see the recommended strategies. You can for example, deploy multiple microservices into a single VM but they should vary by type and not be completely representative of your entire application for resiliency and availability purposes. One container per VM would be overkill and in some ways take away advantages of containers.

Comment: Not "one container per VM" - one microservice per environment, whether it's a container or a VM...but a whole VM for one service is so wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

Its less to do with difficulty but more with respect availability. In other words, if you have multiple microservices of different types and deploy all of them in a single VM and the VM crashes, you lose all of your microservices.

In addition, deploying all the services on the same VM defeats the purpose of using microservices to elastically scale different services, some of which may be receiving a higher load than others. For instance, if you have two services A and B with service B receiving significantly more traffic than A, B will hog all resources. You may potentially want to deploy B on larger servers or its own server to accommodate the load with little performance interruptions cascading to service A.

Comment: This makes sense in a high-availability environment. It's related to disaster prevention and recovery?

Comment: Yep primarily. Looking back at this, I might have misinterpreted the question a little bit. I thought the author meant all microservices into a single VM ie. I thought he/she was asking if my application has 3 services and 3 services on the same VM. Basically, if the VM crashes, you lose one instance of every one of the service, reducing availability. Some sort of randomization is generally a better principle. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The answer to this is relatively simple.. You “can” put all your eggs (containers) in one basket (host) .. But you’ll have better reliability if you spread them out

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to begin with its only a recommendation, not a diktat. You will need to take a call based on your specific needs.

One of the most important need for a microservice architecture is that services needs to  scale independently. Many people including Martin Fowler [wrote about the characteristics](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) of microservices. When you deploy multiple services to one VM this is difficult. Also, same VM will restrict the autonomy of team who should have complete ownership of the service.